# How can I give System password locking pattern to my Android app?

Tags: android, android-security, applocker

When users device has some locking pattern on android or password, can my application make use of it? Does android allow my application to have system locking enabled ? Which APIs of Android do that purpose?

Comment: I've removed the last sentence of your question because asking for libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: like this changes anything in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by this class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)
Did not understand it exactly but before using your application or accessing certain part of your application can be authenticated with phone lock screen, using this class